# I'm trying to install sample data

Tags: magento2, module, installation, sample-data

The "https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/sample-data-media/magento-sa
mple-data-media-100.4.0.0.zip" file could not be written to C:\xampp2\htdoc
s\myhikmadh/vendor/composer/tmp-158e118cd3c775dc66f63508048335ae.zip: Faile
d to open stream: Permission denied

show's this denied msg!

Answer (score 2):

Can You Please use sudo with the commands.
Because its related to your permissions